# Return lastInsertId to controller and storing retrieving in Session

Tags: mysql, session, zend-framework

I am storing the log in datetime and other $data in the database in my Model and get the id of the inserted row like this:

```
$db = Zend_Db_Table_Abstract::getDefaultAdapter();
$db->insert('mylog', $data);
$mylog_id =  $db->lastInsertId();
return ($mylog_id);
```

The value $mylog_id exist when I echo it from the model but is empty on return. In my login controller I want to store this value in the session so I can use it to set log out datetime later:

```
$sessionUserAuth = new Zend_Session_Namespace('Zend_User_Auth');
$sessionUserAuth->log_id = $log_id;
```

How do i get $mylog_id to store it in the session?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call the variable with executing the function, not after, like this:
In the controller

```
$myClass = new myClass();
$mylog_id = $myClass->myfunction($data) //this is the function which returns the value
```

now $mylog_id is available in the controller to store it in the session.

```
$sessionUserAuth->log_id = $mylog_id;
```